# BootstrapError for RxAndroid

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-android

I'm going to use RxJava and RxAndroid.
I wrote a simple Observable. (bellow code)

```
Observable<Task> taskObservable = Observable
                .fromIterable(DataSource.createTasksList())
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());
```

but I get BootstrapError! (bellow error)

```
java.lang.BootstrapMethodError: Exception from call site #1 bootstrap method
```

I have dependencies:

```
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava3:rxandroid:3.0.0'
    implementation "io.reactivex.rxjava3:rxjava:3.0.2"
```

(I also used 3.0.0 for rxjava)

Comment: Add the dependencies you are using for RX .. Add the gradle file in question actually ..

Comment: i tried the same code in a brand new project and it works like a charm!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

include this in your Gradle app-level file

```
 compileOptions {

       sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
       targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8

}
```